# How to use tensorflow serving in external directory using bazel

Tags: tensorflow, bazel, tensorflow-serving

I have a repository, in the following hierarchy :

```
Project 
  -Dockerfile
  -src
     -serving (unchanged repo of TensorFlow serving)
       -WORKSPACE
       -tesnsorflow-serving
       -...
       -...
     -face_ver
       -model_train.py
       -...
       -...
```

Then how to build target 'model_train.py' in 'face_ver', without changing any file in 'serving' directory, using bazel (bazel build)

Please, post the code of sample BUILD file and WORKSPACE file(if required) to be placed in face_ver.